# Cannot deploy SQL with Docker and Azure Data Studio on Mac 10.14

Tags: sql, azure

I am following the instructions on this video located here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUWItrX7hmA

I have docker working and when I run

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password@" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

The output I get is

[image: terminal]

When I then go over to Azure Data studio and put in the following inputs however

[image: azure]

The output I get is:

One solution recommended was to turn off Firewall but, one, it seems that you need to be connected to SQL to do that, and two, I find it hard to believe that that would be necessary since I am just connecting to an image designed for tutorials, three, I can't figure out how to do it.

[image: output]

I should also point out that I haven't found one instance of someone else experiencing error code 35.

I should also add that when I look at the log of the image in Docker I get the following, this is a different image from the previous but I'm having the same problem

[image]

########## UPDATE

https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2017/01/error-17836-length-specified-in-network-packet-payload-did-not-match-number-of-bytes-read-the-connection-has-been-closed.html

i did some research on error 17836 and found this

> Question: This error appeared in the SQL Server Logs today.

> Error: 17836, Severity: 20, State: 14. Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library. [CLIENT: an_ip]

> How can I find out what application is attempting to connect ?

> Answer: The most common reason for this error are Nessus scanners  or similar detection intrusion systems. They usually scan servers looking for vulnerabilities. It’s not obvious from the logs – but you can build a correlation between the timings in the SQL Server Error logs and the Nessus Scanner schedules \ logs. The first clue is the CLIENT details specified in the error log. Use the nslookup command to find the FQDN. It may be obvious from the client name , and you can contact the server owner to find out if there are any applications attempting to connect.

I don't understand what this means.

############ SECOND UPDATE

I was previously using an IP address at work.  I'm home now and am no longer encounter error 17836 but I still have the same problems and cannot connect to the SQL server.  Here is the log for Docker instance:

[image: docker]

Answer (score 0):

I had to write localhost instead of local in the Azure server input box.